# How to stop a TransformBlock from processing remaining queued messages based on a condition?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Below is the code for a simple workflow using TPL DataFlow in a Console project.

Three Test objects, TestA, TestB and TestC are posted into the starting bufferBlock. This is linked to a TransformBlock which evaluates each tests' `PerformTestAsync()` method that returns a `Task<TestResult>`. The TransformBlock is linked to an ActionBlock which writes the test result to the Console.

All this appears to work fine. However, what I am struggling to do is change the code so that the FIRST time `await t.PerformTestAsync()` returns `TestResult.Failed` I want the TransformBlock NOT to process anymore messages and certainly not to pass out any more to the ActionBlock except for the failed result. So, for my example code, I would only like to see "OK", and "Failed" in the console window, and for `testC.PerformTestAsync()` never to have been called at all.

How might I be able to achieve this?

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create workflow blocks
        var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<TestBase>();
        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<TestBase, TestResult>(async t => await t.PerformTestAsync());
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<TestResult>(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
        // Link Blocks
        bufferBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

        // Create Tests
        var tests = new List<TestBase>() { new TestA(), new TestB(), new TestC() };

        // Post them into start of workflow
        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            bufferBlock.Post<TestBase>(test);
        }
        bufferBlock.Complete();

        actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}


public enum TestResult
{
    OK,
    Error,
    Failed
}

public abstract class TestBase
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public TestBase(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
    public abstract Task<TestResult> PerformTestAsync();

}


public class TestA : TestBase
{
    public TestA() : base("Test A")
    {
    }

    public override Task<TestResult> PerformTestAsync()
    {
        // Do some processing for this test...
        return Task.FromResult(TestResult.OK);
    }
}

public class TestB : TestBase
{
    public TestB() : base("Test B")
    {
    }

    public override Task<TestResult> PerformTestAsync()
    {
        // Do some processing for this test...
        return Task.FromResult(TestResult.Failed);
    }
}

public class TestC : TestBase
{
    public TestC() : base("Test C")
    {
    }

    public override Task<TestResult> PerformTestAsync()
    {
        // Do some processing for this test...
        return Task.FromResult(TestResult.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `await t.PerformTestAsync()` returns `TestReuslt.Failed`, throw an exception. That will fault the flow and prevent any further processing. The flow will then complete in a faulted state. No further items would be processed.

```
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<TestBase, TestResult>(async t =>
{
    var result = await t.PerformTestAsync();
    if (result == TestResult.Failed)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return result;
});
```

Note that the exception you throw will be propagated to the `Completion` task of the final block, i.e. your `ActionBlock`. When you await that task you'll be able to handle the faulted flow or ignore as you choose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I can see how what you describe will work. However, I was hoping for a solution that maybe was less drastic than throwing an exception. My scenario is one that can be anticipated, so it feels more right to code accordingly as opposed to throw exceptions which should really be left for exceptional circumstances. But, maybe this is a case where that just isn't possible?

Comment: There are other options, like setting a flag for the block to ignore messages, but if you want the block to stop receiving messages into it's queue the block must be faulted or cancelled. Therefore you could combine the two approaches, cancel the block to prevent accepting new messages and setting a flag to ignore messages already in the queue. But handling the exception and re-initializing the flow may be the easier route.

Comment: I think you're right and the exception approach might just be the pragmatic way to deal with things. Thanks again.